# What's wrong with my differentiation of this implicit function

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

$$\sec\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)=e^a$$

Taking $\sec^{-1}$,

$$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\sec^{-1} (e^a)$$

Now I simply ignore the Right Hand Side as its differentiation is $0$ anyway, so I replace it with $k$ for now. On the other hand (pun not intended), the differentiation of the LHS seems a bit more tricky so I substitute $x$ with $a \cos\theta $ and $y$ with $a \sin\theta $ and then proceed.

$$\frac{a^{2}\cos^{2}\theta -a^{2}\sin^2\theta}{a^{2}\cos^{2}\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}=k$$

Removing the $a^2$ to make it more friendly, the equation becomes

$$\frac{\cos^{2}\theta -\sin^{2}\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta +\sin^2\theta}=k$$

Using the Trigonometric identities

$$\cos2\theta=k$$

Now differentiating

$$-2\sin2\theta=0$$

$$\sin2\theta=0$$

$$2\sin\theta \cos\theta =0$$

and so

$$2\cdot\frac{x}{a}\cdot\frac{y}{a}=0$$

that should be giving me

$$xy=0$$

whose differentiation is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$$

But the answer given is different.

Comment: Are you differentiating with respect to $\theta$ , $x$ or $y$? You can't switch midway unless you use the chain rule.

Comment: Your solution is wrong for several reasons. The equation $xy=0$ you got is **after differentiating**, after which you differentiate again giving the **second derivative**.  Secondly, your substitutions are **wrong** because it assumes that $x^2+y^2=a^2$, that is, it introduces another equation of dependency between $y$ and $x$.

Comment: @Trebor The first time I differentiated I did with respect to $θ$ and I got an equation that I realised I could manipulate to get another simpler equation $xy=0$... was that step incorrect?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Oh i see where I went wrong, but I don't quite get your first statement. While doing the second differentiation i got $\:\frac{dy}{dx}$ anyway, which is what I was after. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: @Adil: I certainly don't understand what you wrote. What I was trying to say in going from $\cos 2\theta=k$ to $xy=0$, you differentiated **once**. Then, you went from $xy=0$ to your final answer where you differentiated **again**. You **differentiated two times** actually. My second point was that you cannot substitute $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=a\sin\theta$ because in doing so, you actually are introducing **another** relation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Patricio: What are the ```\:``` used for? I haven't seen them and they are just adding additional spaces, which don't look quite nice to me. (Adil, you can ignore this comment.)

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Yupp i understood the 2nd point well and good, but I can't grasp my head around why I can't differentiate twice. Trebor just said, "You can't switch midway unless you use the chain rule". Regarding your comment, yes I differentiated twice but whats wrong with it?

Comment: @ultralegend They were already there in the OP question and I didn't change them. The only editing I did was to transform $cos$ into $\cos$ and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has serious drawbacks:

1. You use the substitution $(x,y)=(a\cos\theta, a\sin\theta)$. (This $a$ conflicts with the $a$ in the problem, but it doesn't matter much.) Now, doing so, you introduce another dependency of $y$ on $x$, which is wrong.
2. You had $\cos2\theta=k$. Differentiating gives $xy=0$. Okay, but note that this relation between $x$ and $y$ is entirely new, not to do with the original relation.

To see this, consider the relation $x^2-6x+4=k$. Differentiating gives $2x-6=0$ *i.e.* $x=3$. But does $x=3$ satisfy the original equation? No. Why? Because the differentiated relation is distinct from your original relation.

Similarly, in your case, $\cos2\theta=k$ is satisfied by some $x$ and $y$, but these $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily the same as the $x$ and $y$ you get on differentiating, $xy=0$.

---

As for your problem, you can simplify the differentiation by using $$\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}-1$$

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear. :)

Comment: Noww i got your point, Thanks!